# python Flink instalation Failed to find the file /flink-1.12-SNAPSHOT-bin/flink-1.12-SNAPSHOT/opt/flink-python_*.jar

Tags: maven, apache-flink, pyflink

I am following [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/flinkDev/building.html#build-flink) for installing Flink

After installing all the dependencies mentioned there. Which ran perfectly well

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/flink
mvn clean install -DskipTests
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dfast
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd flink
python -m pip install -r flink-python/dev/dev-requirements.txt
```

I was executing this command

```
cd flink-python; python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

I am getting this error for the above command

```
Failed to find the file /home/user_name/flink/flink-dist/target/flink-1.12-SNAPSHOT-bin/flink-1.12-SNAPSHOT/opt/flink-python_*.jar.
```

I also did `mvn install` on top level module.

Where can I get this jar file?

***(EDIT)***

I was wrong I had an issue while MVN build

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project flink-table-api-java: Compilation failure
```

That is the reason my jars where not created.

Answer (score 0):

If your mvn build is successful, the flink-python jar will be built.You should execute the mvn build command in the flink directory e.g.
`cd flink; mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: sorry i did't mention while mvn build i got this error [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project flink-table-api-java: Compilation failure

Comment: hey i tried again still facing the same problem Which version should i be using are the latest version stable

Comment: You better use the 3.2.5 version of maven officially recommended by flink

Comment: I have Apache Maven 3.6.0